# Oracle REGEXP- How do I get the next string

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G and have the following field NAME with the following strings:

```
NAME
'String having ZT-01183 - App # 2'
'This String having AG-01183 with - Apps # 4'
```

I am using the following regular expression but what I get is the following: ZT-01183 - App # 2 and AG-01183 with - Apps # 4.

```
CASE 
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(NAME, 'ZT-|AG-|having') 
    THEN regexp_replace(NAME, '^.*? having ','')
    END AS NEW_NAME
```

I only want to get the very next string in the statement so the results should be AG-01183 and ZT-01183.  I am instead getting everything after having.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
THEN regexp_replace(name, '.*having ([^ ]+).*', '\1')
```

EDIT:

my original idea of using lookbehind seemed to have been scuppered by Oracle not seemingly being able to use lookbehind.  My edit uses groups to get back what you appear to want.

Comment: This seems to only come up with null results... any clue why I only want the string directly after having

Comment: Thanks this seems to work now I just have to check to make sure the strings can't ever come in as non space delimited.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
THEN regexp_substr(NAME, '[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{5}')
```